# How can i move some files from a directory to an other directory using a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I used this command to move some files from a directory to an other using a batch script:

```
xcopy "pippo\*.*" /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\pippo2"
```

and it worked; it copied all files that are in the folder "pippo" to the folder "pippo2".

But when I have to run my .bat file as administrator it says that it can't find the file named `*.*`, but `*.*` indicate all files with all extension that are into the folder named "pippo" !
So, why does it say that it can't find the file `*.*` , what's wrong in my command ?

Comment: You're not using DOS, you're using the Windows command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably where you are running the batch file from.  When you elevate to administrative rights, I believe the default location is `C:\Windows\System32`.  Try using full file path in your batch file.

Answer (score 0):

This batch will copy from the directory `pippo` **relative** to your current directory. In all probability, the `current directory` when run as administrator is different from the current directory when run as a `user`.

You could check this by inserting some code before and after:

```
echo %cd%
xcopy "pippo\*.*" /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\pippo2"
pause
```

(just temporarily)

If the directory shown is different in the two modes, then you need to change the directory in administrator mode or specify exactly where `pippo` is,

```
xcopy "c:\full\path\to\pippo\*.*" /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\pippo2"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, please specify full path.

```
xcopy "D:\yourSourceFolder\" /S "E:\yourDest\"
```

or

```
xcopy "D:\yourSourceFolder\*.*" /S "E:\yourDest\"
```

don't forget trailing slash in the dest folder , or dos will treat you is this file or folder.

Thanks.